# Backtracking is not working for printing all combinations of a string?

Tags: java, dynamic-programming, backtracking, recursive-backtracking

I'm trying to print all the permutations of a string. But, despite my best efforts i'm not able to get the required output for my code. Can someone explain me what's wrong with my code? I've been trying this for many hours and failed miserably.

The output for the below code is:-

abc

This is the permute function for backtrack:-

```
int i, l = 2;
void permute(String str, int n)
{
    for(i=n;i<=l;i++)
    {
        if(n==l)
        {
            System.out.println(swap(str,n,i));
            return;
        }
        else
            permute(swap(str,n,i),n+1);
    }
}
```

This is the main function that runs the above code:-

```
public static void main(String args[])
{
    BacktrackTest bt=new BacktrackTest();
    String c="abc";
    bt.permute(c,0);
}
```

This is the code for swap:-

```
String swap(String st, int s1, int s2)
{
    char chr[] = st.toCharArray();
    char t;
    t = chr[s1];
    chr[s1] = chr[s2];
    chr[s2] = t;
    st = String.valueOf(chr);
    return st;
}
```

Comment: Is that increment condition in de for-loop `i++` as it should be? Shouldn't it be `i--`?

Comment: n will be the starting index of the string and l is the ending. The loop runs from n to l. So, it should be i++

Comment: I tried your code and it's working just fine. It outputs `abc acb bac bca cba cab` with each permutation in its own line. Are you sure the code you're running is the same that the code in your question? EDIT: my bad, I made a slight modification when copy pasting, see my answer.

Comment: Seriously? I'm surprised! How did u run it? I ran it in eclipse

Comment: It worked man. Silly mistake as pointed out in the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't define `i` outside of `permute` method. Try this:

```
int l = 2;
void permute(String str, int n)
{
    for(int i=n;i<=l;i++)
    {
        if(n==l)
        {
            System.out.println(swap(str,n,i));
            return;
        }
        else
            permute(swap(str,n,i),n+1);
    }
}
```

If you declare `i` outside the `for` loop, it's value is not "restored" for the caller after the return.
In your example, when you enter `if(n==l)`, the value of `i` is 2, but after you `return;` it is still 2 because of its global scope. So in the next iteration it gets increased to 3, thus `i<=l` turns out false and the program ends.
If you declare `i` it inside the loop, after you `return;` it will be back at 1 so the loop can continue.

Comment: Can you please hint on why this is a problem?

Comment: Yup, just added the explanation.

Comment: I think i get it. The i when outside will have a value already when one iteration and then when the function is called recursively, it clashes. Right?

Comment: Right, you got it :)